# Почему при длительной задаче происходит дисконект с rabbitmq?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

Почему при длительной задаче происходит дисконект с rabbitmq?

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(rabbitmqConf['user'], rabbitmqConf['password'])
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(rabbitmqConf['host'], rabbitmqConf['port'], '/', credentials, socket_timeout=20)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue=rabbitmqConf['queueName'], durable=True)
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=rabbitmqConf['queueName'])
channel.start_consuming()
```

При выполнении длительной команды (~10 мин) и при вызове

```
ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

pymongo выдает следующую ошибку

```
(-1, "ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 1005
```

Answer (score 0):

Код этой ошибки значит, что соединение разорванно по какой то причине. Например - неактивность или сетевые проблемы.

Отловите исключение и повторите соединение заново. После этого вы получите последний не подтвержденный таск.